# Jquery page event order

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready, dynatree

I am using the dyna tree jQuery plugin. I have added some data to each node that I retrieve using the in built functions, this is working fine.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     // Loads tree
     $("#TreeManGrp").dynatree({
         initAjax: {
             url: "/Terminals/Refresh/"
         },
         onActivate: function (node) {
             if (node.data.href) {
                 window.open(node.data.href, "_self");
             }
         },
         persist: true,
         noLink: false,
         fx: {
             height: "toggle",
             duration: 200
         },

         success: function (node) {
             alert("Done");
         }

     });
 });
```

When a user clicks a node, it will reload the page, and the clicked node is given a flag of active.

Dyna Tree has this function to get the active node

```
var node = $("#TreeManGrp").dynatree("getActiveNode");
```

I want to get the active node on page load, so stuck this in `document.ready`. The issue seems to be that as the function runs in document ready the active node hasn't actually been set to active.

I did a bit of research and `$(window).load(function () {` is meant to load after `document.ready`, yet the node is always null still.

If I call `getActiveNode` on a button click it is fine, as I assume the dyna tree has done its part and set the node to active.

Any ideas?

Comment: How is that related to `removeClass`?

Comment: this plugin is using cookies or local store to save its session status ?

Comment: You are calling it before the tree has rendered!

Comment: How is that related to removeClass?---Oops sorry, that was somethign I was goign to ask t'other day but didnt need too.

Comment: You are calling it before the tree has rendered! -- I know, you're meant to answer my question not just repeat it to me.

Comment: this plugin is using cookies or local store to save its session status ? --- Yes thats right. Though it would be a lot of work to get this info myself, and i would still have the issue of where to put the code to ensure the tree is fully loaded.

Comment: I'm not familiar with dynatree myself, but a quick look at the documentation would suggest you can get the active node after the ajax request is complete, using `ajaxOptions.success(node)`.  See here... http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/dynatree-doc.html#h5.1

Comment: Thanks Archer, I was just looking at this myself. Ill post if its what im after

Comment: To add to that, `.load()` executes after everything in the DOM is loaded.  It does not take into account any dynamically added elements or data, such as Ajax calls.

Comment: Ok, so this isnt goign to work no matter what event Ive put it in. I tried the success callback (ive edited above code) but it still doesnt work. Does that look right. (sory Im no JS expert).